# Can we have @name in answers, too? (name from any user participating in the Q&A)

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I have seen it that people want to point to a certain user in an answer.

They write the name as plain text. @name is not available/there's no notification.

Reasons for that include:
 - They want to expand on some information given in a comment to a question. 
 - They want to add to some existing answer, but cannot edit, because the content would change the answer too much.

Maybe *user* posted a link only comment, which could be turned into a full answer by *answerer*. Such answers often start with "As found in the comments...". I think it would be good to notify *user* about *answerer's* new answer based on his comment. Maybe he only had time to drop the link in a comment and now can add to an existing post. Or maybe *answerer* draws some conclusion *user* didn't intend with his comment/answer.

In either way, I think being notified can be an improvement. So can we please have @name available in answers, too? The possible names to choose from would be all the users who commented on the question or posted an answer.

Comment: I don't see the utility in notifying. If you want to link to something, link to the comment, answer, question, or profile page. The system can't guess which one is appropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answers should stand on their own.

If any of the other answers were deleted, or any of the accounts involved were renamed, the answer should **still work and be readable and be applicable**. In other words, the question plus *any one answer to that question* should form a atomic whole.

As such, there is *absolutely no place* in answers for references to other users. This is not a social network, this is a question and answer site.

If you want to notify another participant, you can always comment on their answer. Remember that such comments should be transient and are subject to deletion.

Comment: This is not to expand on a comment or other answer, but to give proper credit to its author. Pretty much the same as posting example code and a link to where this code is from.

Comment: @null: then just link to the account, or rather, to the original post.

Comment: @null when I have to do that, I usually turn my answer into community wiki, and start it with "As user123321 said" (with a link to his profile), and then paraphrase or copy/paste. Why would we need this?